# Convert enum multiple values to Json in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Here I have a Rest Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/mobileNumber", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
        public ResponseEntity<ResponseBack> sentResponse() {
    
            return new ResponseEntity<ResponseBack>(ResponseBack.LOGIN_SUCCESS, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    
        }
```

My `Enum` Class

```
public enum ResponseBack {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS(0, " success"), LOGIN_FAILURE(1, " failure");

    private long id;
    private final String message;

    // Enum constructor
    ResponseBack(long id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

When I get the response back from the controller I am getting it as

```
"LOGIN_SUCCESS"
```

What I require is

```
{
    "id": "0",
    "message": "success"   
}
```

How can I deserialize it to Json and send response, is there any annotation for it.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use JsonFormat annotation

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum ResponseBack {
...
```

So you tell that the Json representation of this enum will be the whole object. If you want a specific field to be returned (for example message field) you can annotate the method with JsonValue annotation

```
@JsonValue
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
```